# Selenium WebDriver: How to set focus when running exe, file for windows authentication.

Tags: java, selenium

In My web driver (`Selenium`) script I am running `exe` file before getting windows popup.

`java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\winauthen.exe"); // Windows Authentication popup
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='home']/div[2]")).click();`

Its running fine if focus always on the window But  if simultaneously I am working something other the user name and password get print/type on the active page not on the Authentication popup.

**How to set focus?** that it run weather I am looking in to it or not.

Thanks in advance.